# why rc and rc.x are linked

Tags: linux, rc

May I know why we have them linked ? is there any reason behind this ?

```
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root    7 Aug  7  2015 rc -> rc.d/rc
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   15 Aug  7  2015 rc.sysinit -> rc.d/rc.sysinit
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   13 Aug  7  2015 rc.local -> rc.d/rc.local
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   10 Aug  7  2015 rc1.d -> rc.d/rc1.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   10 Aug  7  2015 rc0.d -> rc.d/rc0.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   10 Aug  7  2015 rc4.d -> rc.d/rc4.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   10 Aug  7  2015 rc3.d -> rc.d/rc3.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   10 Aug  7  2015 rc2.d -> rc.d/rc2.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   10 Aug  7  2015 rc6.d -> rc.d/rc6.d
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root   10 Aug  7  2015 rc5.d -> rc.d/rc5.d
```

Answer (score 2):

For compatibility across different software mostly.  If you install an application that wants to store files in /etc/rc.d/rc but your *nix flavor doesn't have an /etc/rc.d/rc, your application is going to complain, and probably won't start properly.  This way applications can store their files in any number of relatively standard locations and they'll likely be found when the system goes to look where it expects them to be.